# How to handle error exceptions with PythonPing?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to ping a list of computers but I keep getting a socket error on the last computer name which is not a valid computer.  How do I go about handling this error?

```
from pythonping import ping
import socket

list = ["usadandc1", "usadandc2", "usadandc3", "alsdkfasd"]

for host in list:
    result = ping(host, count=1)
    if result.success():
        print(host ,'online')
    else:
        print(host, 'Offline')
```

Here is the output:

```
usadandc1 online
usadandc2 online
usadandc3 online
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\PythonPing.py", line 7, in <module>
    result = ping(host, count=1)
  File "C:\Users\usa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pythonping\__init__.py", line 52, in ping
    comm = executor.Communicator(target, provider, timeout, socket_options=options, verbose=verbose, output=out)
  File "C:\Users\usa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pythonping\executor.py", line 224, in __init__
    self.socket = network.Socket(target, 'icmp', source=None, options=socket_options)
  File "C:\Users\usa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pythonping\network.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.destination = socket.gethostbyname(destination)
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? If you know it's not a valid computer, why do you try to ping it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was testing out different scenarios because eventually I will be pinging a list of about 3000 computer which I'm sure will have invalid computer names.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pythonping import ping
import socket

list = ["google.com", "usadandc2", "usadandc3", "alsdkfasd"]

for host in list:

    try:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
        result = ping(ip, count=1)
        if result.success():
            print(host, 'online')

    except socket.error:
        print(host, 'Offline')
```